# Keep border radius consistent despite size of Div

Tags: html, css, height, border

Currently when my div expands, the border radius changes depending on the height of the div. You will notice that the corners are pushed in/out more or less depending on the div's height. Is there a way to preserve the border radius so it says the same regardless of the div's height?

I recommend viewing snippet as a full page or expanding!

```js
var toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
var test = document.getElementById('test');

toggle.onclick = function() {
  if (test.style.height == "300px") {
    test.style.height = "500px"
  } else {
    test.style.height = "300px" 
  }
 }
```

```css
#test {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 85%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 3%;
    border-radius: 5px / 200px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: green;
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>

<div id="toggle">toggle
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `border-radius: 5px  200px;` instead `border-radius: 5px / 200px;`

Comment: no, I should not be using that, it changes the look completely

Comment: *it says the same regardless of the div's height?* --> define what you mean by *the same* because it's looks the same for me